# Struggle to read csv file

Tags: scala, csv

I am struggling to figure out how i can work with CSV files in scala. I have this code and i have tried to implement various types of codes for csv reading etc, but not been able to actually read a file at all. the // read file is me trying / my late4st attempemt but i get an : object Source is not a member of package org.apache.http.io
[error]     val filename = io.Source.fromFile("countries.csv")

Cn someone help me out what am i doing wrong ?

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons._
import org.apache.http._
import org.apache.http.client._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import java.util.ArrayList
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import scala.io.Source

case class Teacher(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
//case class Country(name: String, region: String, population: Int, area: Int, popDensity: Int, coastline: Int, netmigration: Int, infantMortality: Int, gdp: Int, literacy: Int, phones: Int, arable: Int, crops: Int, other: Int, climate: Int, birthrate: Int,deathrate: Int, agriculture: Int, industry: Int, service: Int)

object HttpJsonPostTest extends App {
    //read data 
    val filename = io.Source.fromFile("countries.csv")
    for(line <- filename.getLines){
        val col = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}|${cols(3)}")
    }



    // create our object as a json string
    val marius = new Teacher("Lucas", "Geitle", 32)
    val mariusAsJson = new Gson().toJson(marius)

    // add name value pairs to a post object
    val post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/big_data_course1")
    val nameValuePairs = new ArrayList[NameValuePair]()
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", mariusAsJson))
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))

    // send the post request
    val client = new DefaultHttpClient
    val response = client.execute(post)
    println("--- HEADERS ---")
    response.getAllHeaders.foreach(arg => println(arg))
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas! Welcome :) Can you explain your desired behaviour would be?

Comment: change `io.Source.fromFile` to `scala.io.Source.fromFile` — another one of your imports has brought something else named `io` into scope

Comment: My plan was that wehen i upload the new code to the DB it wuld show me all key values ( country names) but i havent been able to do that. I only get the last country in the csv file